# CryptoAPI: difference Between CALG_* and BCRYPT_*_ALGORITHM

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, cng

What is the difference between `CALG_*` and `BCRYPT_*_ALGORITHM`

for example: SHA_256 is defined both as:

`#define CALG_SHA_256 (ALG_CLASS_HASH|ALG_TYPE_ANY|ALG_SID_SHA_256)`

and

`#define BCRYPT_SHA256_ALGORITHM L"SHA256"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, CALC_* are crypto algorithm from crypto api from day 1.

BCRYPT are the one for CNG (crypto next gen) which replace (in a long time?) the legacy crypto API.